Set User or Document Property while creating a new Doc
I am working on a Google Apps Script Project.
The script takes in some parameters, and creates a new Google Doc.
This script will be exposed as a POST API.
I want to store some of the request parameters in the Property Store at the Document or User level.
But from the documentation, it looks like the PropertyService.getUserProperties() and PropertyService.getDocumentProperties() return only when there is an active Document opened by a user.
Is there a way to set Document level properties at the time of creating the document?
I want to be able to do something like this:
function doPost(e) {
  var requestData = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);
  var documentName = requestData.documentName;
  var documentExtId = requestData.documentExtId;
  
  var result = createDoc(documentName, documentExtId);
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(result)).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
}

function createDoc(documentName, documentExtId) {
  // Create a new Google Doc
  var doc = DocumentApp.create(documentName);
    
  // Get the ID of the created document
  var docId = doc.getId();
  
  // Get the URL to edit the document
  var docUrl = 'https://docs.google.com/document/d/' + docId + '/edit';
  
  
  // I want to be able to do something like this....
  PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties().setProperty("documentExtId", documentExtId);
  
  // Return the URL
  return {
    url: docUrl
  };
}



As another approach, how about using the custom properties with Drive API? Ref The custom properties of Drive API can store the data for each file. And, when the custom properties are used, they can be managed by Drive API from your script.
But, there is a limitation for the custom properties as follows. Ref So, first, please confirm between this limitation and the value of documentExtId in your script.


Maximum of 100 custom properties per file, totaled from all sources.
Maximum of 30 public properties per file, totaled from all sources.
Maximum of 30 private properties per file from any one application.
Maximum of 124 bytes per property string (including both key and value) in UTF-8 encoding. For example, a property with a key that's 10 characters long can only have 114 characters in the value. Similarly, a property that requires 100 characters for the value can use up to 24 characters for the key.


When this is reflected in your script, it becomes as follows.
Modified script:
In this modification, please modify createDoc as follows. And, please enable Drive API v3 at Advanced Google services.
function createDoc(documentName, documentExtId) {
  const customProperty = { properties: { documentExtId: documentExtId } }; // or const customProperty = { appProperties: { documentExtId: documentExtId } };
  const docId = Drive.Files.create({ mimeType: MimeType.GOOGLE_DOCS, name: documentName, ...customProperty }, null, { fields: "id", supportsAllDrives: true }).id;
  var docUrl = 'https://docs.google.com/document/d/' + docId + '/edit';
  return { url: docUrl };
}


You can use const customProperty = { properties: { documentExtId: documentExtId } }; and/or const customProperty = { appProperties: { documentExtId: documentExtId } };. About properties and appProperties, you can see the detailed information at the official document. Ref

When you want to retrieve the stored property, please use the following script. When properties is set, the values can be obtained by console.log(properties). When appProperties is set, the values can be obtained by console.log(appProperties).
function sample() {
  const docId = "###"; // Please set the document ID.

  const { properties, appProperties } = Drive.Files.get(docId, { fields: "properties,appProperties", supportsAllDrives: true });
  console.log(properties);
  console.log(appProperties);
}



References:

Method: files.create of Drive API v3
Method: files.get of Drive API v3


The easiest solution to store an ID in the document would probably be to write it in the document as text. See DocumentApp.Text.

it looks like the PropertyService.getUserProperties() and PropertyService.getDocumentProperties() return only when there is an active Document opened by a user.

PropertyService.getDocumentProperties() indeed only works when the script project is bound to a document. You cannot use it in a stand-alone script project such as a doPost() web app that is not attached to anything.
On the other hand, PropertiesService.getUserProperties() documentation tells:

Gets a property store that only the current user can access, and only within this script.

There is no requirement for an active document.
